# Symfony4 How to get objects with query builder

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4, query-builder

(Hi!),
I need to get objects from a query builder, but I collect an array, so I have the following error:

> Call to a member function getPropertyName() on array

So I suppose than my request isn't correct, but I don't know how to resolve my problem

```
public function findByYear($year): array
{
    $conn = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM rent_release r WHERE YEAR(`date`) = :yearRequested';
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(['yearRequested' => $year]);

    return $stmt->fetchAll();
}
```

Waiting for your help, thanks :)

Comment: ```public function findByYear($year): array``` there is probably something else to do, but it should be : ```public function findByYear($year): YourEntity```

Comment: Why don't you use `createQueryBuilder`?

Comment: @BentCoder I'm not fluent with DQL ... but I will try it :)

Comment: Also if there are more than one result for your query, it will return array containing objects so you need to iterate through the array and call `getPropertyName` on the items.

Comment: to actually get proper (managed) entities, you have to use the querybuilder or the other repository functions. to create entity managed entities from arrays is waaaay more complicated. I'm not quite certain, if the YEAR function is in the doctrine core, otherwise you should integrate doctrine_extensions (package that includes additional sql functions). anyway, prefer querybuilder!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so, according to comments, I used createQueryBuilder and beberlei/doctrineextensions.

here is the DQL:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('rr')
        ->andWhere('YEAR(rr.date) = :year')
        ->setParameter('year', $year)
        ->orderBy('rr.date', 'ASC')
        ->getQuery();

    return $qb->execute();
```

and in doctrine.yaml I added this:

```
dql:
      string_functions:
        YEAR: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Year
```

and now it works well, thanks all !